# How to show the JSON data in asp.net web form

Tags: asp.net, json

I am Beginner at Asp.net so can anyone plz help me to show the data provided in the below shown JSON Api in Asp.net Step by Step.It be of great help if this is answered.

http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/180/

Answer (score 0):

A good way to use Json in C# is with [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

[JSON.NET - Official site](http://james.newtonking.com/json) will help you work with it.

Example to use it

```
public class User {
    public User(string json) {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jUser = jObject["user"];
        name = (string) jUser["name"];
        teamname = (string) jUser["teamname"];
        email = (string) jUser["email"];
        players = jUser["players"].ToArray();
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string teamname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Array players { get; set; }
}
// Use
private void Run() {
    string json = @"{""user"":{""name"":""asdf"",
         ""teamname"":""b"",""email"":""c"",""players"":[""1"",""2""]}}";
    User user = new User(json);
    Console.WriteLine("Name : " + user.name);
    Console.WriteLine("Teamname : " + user.teamname);
    Console.WriteLine("Email : " + user.email);
    Console.WriteLine("Players:");
    foreach (var player in user.players)
        Console.WriteLine(player);
 }
```